# hive sql join different table as array of structs

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

Let's have table `header`:

```
id |  col1 | col2
1  |  "a" | "b"
2  |  "c" | "d"
```

And table `body`:

```
header_id | body_id | body_col
1         | 6       | "abc"
1         | 7       | "def"
2         | 8       | "ghi"
2         | 9       | "jkl"
```

I want to insert body into header as an array of structs, in json, the result would like this:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  col1: "a",
  col2: "b",
  body: [{body_id: 6, body_col: "abc"}, {body_id: 7, body_col: "def"}]
},
{
  id: 2,
  col1: "c",
  col2: "d",
  body: [{body_id: 8, body_col: "ghi"}, {body_id: 9, body_col: "jkl"}]
}
```

How do I achieve this? AFAIK `collect_set` or `collect_list` won't work, since they only collect whole columns into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start by joining the two dataframes. Then `collect_list` is actually the way to go to achieve what you want. You just need to bind `body_id` and `body_col` together inside a `struct` first.

The code would look like this:

```scala
val result = header
    .join(body.withColumnRenamed("header_id", "id"), Seq("id"))
    .groupBy("id", "col1", "col2")
    .agg(collect_list(struct('body_id, 'body_col)) as "body")
result.show(false)
```

```
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|id |col1|col2|body                |
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|2  |c   |d   |[[8, ghi], [9, jkl]]|
|1  |a   |b   |[[6, abc], [7, def]]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
```

We can also print the schema of the result, which is exactly how your json was built:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- body_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- body_col: string (nullable = true)
```